# Selecting specific using x-path while disregarding certain nodes

Tags: xpath

I have some html that looks pretty much like this.

```
<p>
 <a img src="img src">
 <strong>foo</strong>
 <strong>bar</strong>
 <strong>baz</strong>
 <strong>eek</strong>
 This is the text I want to select using xpath.
</p>
```

How can I select only this particular text node as indicated above using xpath?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short and exact XPath expression that selects the wanted text node.

Answer (score 0):

"/p/text()" xpath expression will select the text from "p" node in above XML (Posted in question).

```
/p/text()[normalize-space()]
```

this will remove trailing spaces  from string. This xpath produces exactly what you want.

There is very good tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

Comment: Actually /p/text() will also return 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' and 'eek'. Trying to avoid that.

Comment: text() function should return you only text in node and not text from child nodes. I have even verified this using firefox XPath checker addon. It works!!!.

Please verify and let me know how you are verifying same.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get at only this particular
>   text element in question using xpath?

**Use**:

```
/p/text()[last()]
```